# Calling SSO-Enabled API From .Net Core API Using Explicit Network Credentials

Tags: c#, .net-core, network-programming, single-sign-on

I'm migrating a WinForms App to a .Net Core (3.1) API and I've run into trouble with a feature which makes a call to a SSO-protected API within our network.

In the WinForms App, I had the following:

```
public async void Authenticate()
{
        var wi = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        var wic = wi.Impersonate();

        try
        {
            // Initial request to grab cookies and redirect endpoint
            var apiEndPoint = $"https://{_host}{_apiPath}";
            var cookieRedirectRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, apiEndPoint);
            var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(cookieRedirectRequest);
            if (response != null)
            {
                var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                foreach (var cookie in response.Headers.GetValues("Set-Cookie"))
                {
                    var parsedCookie = cookie.ToCookie();
                    parsedCookie.Domain = TARGET_DOMAIN;
                    cookieContainer.Add(parsedCookie);
                }
                var redirectURL = response.Headers.GetValues("Location").FirstOrDefault();

                // Add the cookies to the client to continue the authentication
                _httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler()
                {
                    UseDefaultCredentials = true,
                    AllowAutoRedirect = true,
                    ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Automatic,
                    UseCookies = true,
                    CookieContainer = cookieContainer
                });

                // Second request to grab code and state values
                var codeAndStateRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, redirectURL);
                response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(codeAndStateRequest);
...
```

The initial call to the API redirects us to the SSO-authentication page. I use the cookies from that initial response to create my own request so that I can pass in the proper credentials and get back the appropriate SSO tokens (the response the SendSync call on the last line returns back the tokens), which I  then use to authenticate on future requests to the API.

I'm trying to recreate this functionality in .NET Core using a Service Account, and instead of doing the WindowsIdentity impersonation, I'm trying to explicitly set the NetworkCredentials property of my HttpClientHandler:

```
                handler = new HttpClientHandler()
                {
                    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("svc_acct_username", "svc_act_pass", "mydomain"),
                    AllowAutoRedirect = true,
                    ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Automatic,
                    UseCookies = true,
                    CookieContainer = cookieContainer,                        
                };
```

However, the response I'm getting back from my second request is a 401.

This is consistent with what I used to get in my original app -- I would initially get a 401 with a "WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate" header, but then there would be an automatic subsequent request where the network credentials were  passed in and I'd get a 200. I'm not getting this second request with the creds in .Net Core.

I tried the Credentials Cache solution suggested here:
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/24490
But this has not worked.

Thanks in advance for any help you guys can give me. I'm quite stuck!

Quick Edit:
I can recreate the .Net Core behavior in my WinForms app by simply setting the Credentials property of the HttpClientHandler explicitly and setting UseDefaultCredentials = false. So, there's some magic happening by setting UseDefaultCredentials that seemingly can't be recreated when using explicit creds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working with help from a co-worker! The issue is that when you use explicit Network Credentials, you lose the "Negotiate" authentication type, which is what our SSO-endpoint requires. By using a CredentialCache object and setting the Negotiate auth-type explicitly, the call works!

```
var credCache = new CredentialCache { { new Uri("https://example.com"), "Negotiate", new NetworkCredential("svc_acct_user", "svc_acct_password", "mydomain") } };

// Add the cookies to the client to continue the authentication
handler = new HttpClientHandler()
{   
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    Credentials = credCache,
    AllowAutoRedirect = true,
    ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Automatic,
    UseCookies = true,
    CookieContainer = cookieContainer,                        
};
```